# Alternatives to GLCM and Gabor filters to get texture information for image segmentation

Tags: image-processing, textures, image-segmentation, grayscale, glcm

What's a good alternative to **GLCM** and **Gabor filters** to get *texture information* from an 8 bit image (gray-scale)?

The *texture information* is required in order to be used later during the *segmentation* of the image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also use:

1. Size Zone Matrix (powerful for homogeneity/heterogeneity description)
2. Run Length Matrix
3. Local Binary Pattern (widely use)
4. Pattern Spectrum (Granulometry + anti-granulometry)
5. Wavelets (seen in many papers, but never used... even if Gabor is a particular wavelets)